# How can I do 6.months.ago - 1.days.ago in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I achieve the following behavior in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4?

```
Purchase.where('purchase_date <= ?', 6.months.ago - 1.days.ago).each do |purchase|
    # ...
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you actually need as a resut ?

Comment: Can you explain what you want? Do you want to list all the Purchases made 6 months ago (subtracting one day) or do you wanto to list all the Purchases from last 6 months until yeasterday?

Comment: Anyway, you have answers for both cases. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Purchase.where('purchase_date <= ?', 6.months.ago + 1.day).each do |purchase|
```

Comment: Why plus instead of minus?

Comment: @sebkomianos - I assumed the intetntion is `6.months.ago - 1.day.ago = (6.months - 1.day).ago = 6.months.ago + 1.day`

Answer (score 5):

Make a BETWEEN filter? If use ActiveRecord, do this:

```
Purchase.where(purchase_date: 6.months.ago..1.day.ago).each do |purchase|
  ## do .....
end
```

Comment: Should it be `6.months.ago..1.day.ago`?